# Why does cURL work, but my HttpWebRequest does not?

Tags: c#, api, curl, httpwebrequest, ip-address

I'm trying to take the below curl statement and reperform it in a c# method.  The following curl statement works fine (I masked the credentials and IP address) so I'm sure the destination server is willing to play ball:

```
curl -D- -u user:password -X POST --data @data.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://0.0.0.0:8080/rest/api/2/issue/
```

where the data.txt looks like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":{"id": "10000"},
       "summary": "No REST for the Wicked.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using ids for projects and issue types using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {"id": "10002"},
    "customfield_10115" : "3212.12",
    "customfield_10116" : "Client Name",
    "customfield_10117" : "Engagement Name",
    "customfield_10118" : "TEst",
    "customfield_10121" : "2019-11-30",
    "customfield_10120" : "Daily"
   }
}
```

However, when I try and re-perform the above in C#, it's giving me the dreaded I'm-Not-Telling-You-Why-This-Doesn't-Work message: **"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."**

Here's my C# Code.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://0.0.0.0:8080/rest/api/2/issue/");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic user:password");

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {   
                string json = "{\"fields\": {\"project\":{ \"id\": \"10000\"},\"summary\": \"No REST for the Wicked.\",\"description\": \"description text\",\"issuetype\": { \"id\": \"10002\"},\"customfield_10115\" : \"3212.12\",\"customfield_10116\" : \"Client Name\",\"customfield_10117\" : \"Engagement Name\",\"customfield_10118\" : \"Payroll\",\"customfield_10121\" : \"2019-11-30\",\"customfield_10120\" : \"Daily\"}}";
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try making a request to a web server that will just spit out what you sent (like httpbin.org, or create such a server yourself) and inspect the differences.

Comment: Did you [base64](https://www.base64encode.org/) encode your `user:password` in `Autorization` header? make sure it looks like `dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==`. Feel free to snip your traffic with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or any other tool to see what kind of content is transferred and response received.

Comment: Posible it require data to send that changes on each request.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to fenixil who spotted my issue:

Just needed to Base64 the username/password pair.  Works like a champ now!